# Can't link excel data to ArcGis 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, excel

I want to make a shapefile from an excel spreadsheet, after clicking on Add Data button and leading to the folder containing the excel file, it doesn't show any excel spreadsheet and the drop down list of "show of type" just has one option which is "Datasets, Layers and Results" .

Comment: the procedure you described should work, so maybe there's a problem with your installation. can you navigate to the folder via the catalog window (or ArcCatalog) and see the excel spread sheet that way? or have you tried the excel to table tool (ArcToolbox > Conversion Tools > Excel > Excel To Table)?

Comment: thanks it helped, the problem solved after reinstalling the software.

Comment: @asal we like to keep things tidy here. Would you please create an answer to your question, fill in exactly what you did to resolve, and then mark it as correct? Thanks

Comment: glad you got it sorted. did you reinstall ArcGIS or Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by reinstalling ArcGIS 10.2.

Answer (score 0):

what version of excel do you have? - from the [docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//005s0000001w000000)

> If you have an .xlsx file you want to use in ArcGIS but do not have Excel 2007 installed, you will need to install the 2007 Office System Driver

similar, but older, info is [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/08/10/working-with-microsoft-excel-in-arcgis-desktop/)

> ArcGIS can read both XLS and XLSX files, but you may need to install an additional driver on your machine, depending on what version of Microsoft Excel you are using.

Answer (score -2):

Have you already tried the GISconnector for Excel?
https://gisconnector.de/en/testversion-2/
The GISconnector enables a smooth transfer of data and functions between ArcGIS and Excel.

Comment: Are you associated with GISconnector?

Comment: [The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)  To see how others write their disclaimers see https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=disclaimer